# lawn-mower charging outside the area enclosed by perimeter wire

Tags: lawn-mower

My question is about Worx Landroid S WR130E and Worx Landroid S WR091S.

I would like to know if it is possbile to place the docking station outside of the area enclosed in the perimeter wire, just for the charging phase. When the battery is charged, I would bring the mower inside the area enclosed by the perimeter wire, where is the lawn that the robot should cut.

Obviously I don't expect the robot will come back to the docking station automatically; I just would like to know if it is possible to use it in this way to cut the lawn without any damage.

In the meanwhile, I'll get a power source near the lawn to place the docking station in a definitive location inside the lawn area.

Thank you